# I have a problem changing the inside of h1 to #f50569 color

Tags: css, colors

this is the screenshot of my work, [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWbDJ.png  ,and I have a problem filling inside the h1 which is "Adopt me", I am using a google font called "Londrina Shadow" and I wanna fill it with this color "#f50569", I am still a beginner so I really need your help.

Thank you.

```css
h1
{
    font-family: 'Londrina Shadow', cursive;
    font-size: 60px;
    : #f50569;
}
```

Comment: `: #f50569;` Is this a typo or your actual code?

Comment: The font that you have chosen is made up of outlines only. You are not going to be able to fill the inner part of the characters with a colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ['Londrina Shadow'](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Londrina+Shadow) font consists only of outlines. There is no way to fill the empty space between the outlines with colour because these areas are not part of the fonts glyphs.

However, there is another font; ['Londrina Solid'](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Londrina+Solid), that is identical in shape but has a solid appearance, rather than outlines.

You can layer these two fonts to create a filled and outlined effect.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Londrina Solid', cursive;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

h1:after {
  content: "Lorem ipsum";
  font-family: 'Londrina Shadow', cursive;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Londrina+Shadow&family=Londrina+Solid&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>
  Lorem ipsum
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean use `color:#f50569;` ?

```css
h1
{
    font-family: 'Londrina Shadow', cursive;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #f50569;
}
```

```html
<h1>Adopt Me</h1>
```

Comment: I mean inside the word

Answer (score 0):

To set the text color, you use the `color`attribute:

```css
h1
{
    font-family: 'Londrina Shadow', cursive;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #f50569;
}
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: not actually, i"m not looking for the text color, but the for the inside